# Objective C, replacement of retain while using ARC

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I am trying convert a project which uses retain and release to use ARC. The automatic conversion in XCode didn't work out, so I do it by hand. Dealing with release was easy. I am now down to a couple of retain statements like below:

```
UIImage *origImage = [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] retain];
```

How do I convert this to ARC friendly? I tried to use the strong keyword, but complier complained about Use of undeclared identifier 'strong'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UIImage *origImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] ;
```

it is ARC friendly.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `__strong` which is the same as using `strong` for a @property, but for a variable. same with `weak` and `__weak`

```
__strong UIImage *origImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
```

Comment: Or you can just not do anything. ARC will handle this case just fine on it's own.